# R Won't Install Packages (ldpaths)

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, symlink, install.packages

When I try to install the package dplyr (or any other package) I am getting the following errors.  I have reinstalled R (and upgraded) a few times now tonight.  Any suggestions on what might be wrong?  Running R version 3.3 on Linux Mint.  Used the Trusty repo (but also tried others).

ldpaths is a "broken symbolic link to `/etc/R/ldpaths'"

[image: R install error]

Comment: guess you can find where ldpath is `find /usr/lib -name  ldpaths` or `find /etc/R -name  ldpaths` and then edit the softlink to point there

Comment: This likely implies there's something wrong with your R installation -- it's looking for files that are normally bundled as part of an R installation, but they don't exist in yours. How was R installed? Do you have a custom `.Rprofile` or did you modify your installation post-hoc?